# I am getting error when creating new Mongo Store

Tags: mongodb, express

I have to submit the code in 1hr but i am getting error while creating mongoStore. can anyone pls help me fast
https://github.com/Raunak49/paint-app - this is link to my code you can directly commit changes here

```
    Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
C:\Users\raunak\Desktop\paint-app\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
            ^

Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options
```

Comment: instead of ```const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
``` you should do ```const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongo");```. this is what the error is complaning about.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `new MongoDBStore({...})`, you should use `MongoDBStore.create`.
And you should not wrap session by mongodb store.

```js
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongo');

const store = MongoDBStore.create({
    mongoUrl: dbUrl,
    secret: secret,
    touchAfter: 24 * 60 * 60
});

const sessionConfig = {
    store,
    // ...
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig))
```

Comment: Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
C:\Users\raunak\Desktop\paint-app\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
            ^

Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options. this is the error i am getting now

Comment: Why would not you just use `mongoUrl` above given instead of `url`?

Comment: i tried it still isn't working can you make it work and commit the changes